# What is the ideal approach to export reports to Excel and CSV using JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* designer to export reports into *PDF* format and *CSV* formats. Now for the *PDF*
format, everything seems perfect, but when I use the same design to export to *CSV*, the whole
layout goes haywire. I would document all the necessary research i have gathered. Let's have
a look at the report format in *PDF* and then *CSV*.

**PDF Format**

[image: PDF Format for the Report]

**CSV Format**

[image: CSV Format for Report]

Here is the research gathered.

1. *PDF* format is pixel perfect reports where *CSV* reports.
2. We can use [CSVMetaDataExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#csvmetadataexport) in order to just extract the data and set the column names describing the types and data using export parameters. Though i have not used the second option still.

So my basic question is, if we want to use the same template to export *CSV* or *Excel*, we would be obviously running into alignment and width issues. I exported the report to *Excel* as well and in the *Excel* format the results were not at all satisfactory. So in this context, is *JasperReports* really a correct choice to opt for *Excel* and *CSV* formats? If it is, what is the ideal approach to deal with such output formats?

Comment: The *csv* is just a plain-text format. For example, you can not put image to it. Additionally the *MS Office* is not a single application in the whole world for viewing *csv* file.

Comment: Do you need this ones - [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures)?

Comment: See also: [Exporting to Pure Text Format](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/text/index.html#textexport), [Exporting to CSV Format Using Report Metadata](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#csvmetadataexport), [Exporting to XLS Format Using Report Metadata](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#xlsmetadataexport)

Answer (score 4):

In my professional opinion, no.  Don't even bother trying to keep the same template format when your output will change from Visual: PDF/On-Screen/Print and Structured: CSV/Excel etc,.

Alex K mentioned the Advanced Excel Features, and when used well it can generate output on screen that will match Excel. However, your design of the elements must be very tight, meaning avoid spanning cells, absolutely positioned elements, snap to grid or snap to other elements.

If your client/user requires the report to look good and be useable in Excel, then you may very well have to design for an Excel format.